# How can I execute notify-send from root?

Tags: root, privileges, notifications, notify-send

I'm working on a bash script which requires root privileges, but which I'd like to give the ability to notify a non-root user of certain alerts via `notify-send` in GNOME (or any other desktop shell supporting that command). As expected, simply invoking `notify-send` from a root shell doesn't display a notification on the non-root user's desktop.

I've tried to invoke the command via:

```
su -c "notify-send 'my message'" -s /bin/sh someuser
```

(as well as using `/bin/bash`, `/usr/zsh`), but neither of these has had any effect.

How can I invoke `notify-send` from a root shell so that it shows a notification on a (specified) non-root user's desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 su $USER -c "/usr/bin/notify-send 'my message'"
```

The above is how I have done in the past with cron jobs that are run as `root`. Of course you need to specify an actual user in the `$USER` variable.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work under GNOME 3.22.1 with `notify-send` 0.7.7 running on Arch Linux (kernel 4.8.6). Can you confirm whether, in past cases, it's worked with applications which affect a GUI desktop environment?

Comment: I use this in a cron job under Debian with Xfce as desktop environment. I have no machine with Gnome to test on unfortunately.

Comment: Works on xfce mint as well.